# How to set default column value in mysql view?

Tags: mysql

I have a main table, and have to create a special view on it for a legacy system. The legacy system expects a default value for a date **if** the date is missing.

I don't want and cannot change the main table!

```
create table mytable (
    id int,
    customername varchar(50),
    customerdate date,
    key mykey (date)
);

create view myview as
   select id,
   customername,
   ifnull(customerdate, cast('1900-01-01' as date))
from mytable;
```

With this view, I'm losing the **index** functionality of mysql.

Question: how could I add keep mysql using the index, but still setting a default value if the date field is null?

Comment: 'Indexes can be used for views processed using the merge algorithm' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-restrictions.html#:~:text=It%20is%20not%20possible%20to,generation%20of%20the%20temporary%20tables). - please publish the outcome of show create view myview

Comment: `customerdate` in the view should simply be ' 1900-01-01' if `customerdate = null` on the original table. But that's not the point. The point is that mysql won't use the inde `mykey` when `ifnull... cast()` on an indexed field!